# NetBeans closed, and sometime computer restarted, when some jFrame are opened

Tags: java, netbeans-7.4

NetBeans restarts if certain jFrames are opened. These jFrames contain more than 3000 lines (altogether, including pre-defined codes by netbeans). Is the length of the file a problem or there is some other issue?

I could not fix it. Can anybody provide me with the solution? Thanks in advance for all your help.

Log ------------

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>Log Session: Saturday, April 16, 2016 2:06:32 AM PDT
>System Info: 
  Product Version         = NetBeans IDE 7.4 (Build 201310111528) (#6523d6792981)
  Operating System        = Windows XP version 5.1 running on x86
  Java; VM; Vendor        = 1.7.0_51; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 24.51-b03; Oracle Corporation
  Runtime                 = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.7.0_51-b13
  Java Home               = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre
  System Locale; Encoding = en_US (nb); Cp1252
  Home Directory          = C:\Documents and Settings\USER
  Current Directory       = C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4
  User Directory          = C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Application Data\NetBeans\7.4
  Cache Directory         = C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Local Settings\Application Data\NetBeans\Cache\7.4
  Installation            = C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\nb
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\ide
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\extide
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\java
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\apisupport
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\websvccommon
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\profiler
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\harness
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\javafx
                            C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform
  Boot & Ext. Classpath   = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\classes;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar
  Application Classpath   = C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\boot.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\org-openide-modules.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\org-openide-util-lookup.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\org-openide-util.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\locale\boot_ja.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\locale\boot_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\locale\boot_ru.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\locale\boot_zh_CN.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-modules_ja.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-modules_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-modules_ru.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-modules_zh_CN.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-util-lookup_ja.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-util-lookup_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-util-lookup_ru.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-util-lookup_zh_CN.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-util_ja.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-util_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-util_ru.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\lib\locale\org-openide-util_zh_CN.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\lib\dt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\lib\tools.jar
  Startup Classpath       = C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\core\core.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\core\org-openide-filesystems.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\core\locale\core_ja.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\core\locale\core_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\core\locale\core_ru.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\core\locale\core_zh_CN.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\core\locale\org-openide-filesystems_ja.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\core\locale\org-openide-filesystems_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\core\locale\org-openide-filesystems_ru.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform\core\locale\org-openide-filesystems_zh_CN.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\nb\core\org-netbeans-upgrader.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\nb\core\locale\core_nb.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\nb\core\locale\core_nb_ja.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\nb\core\locale\core_nb_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\nb\core\locale\core_nb_ru.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\nb\core\locale\core_nb_zh_CN.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\nb\core\locale\org-netbeans-upgrader_ja.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\nb\core\locale\org-netbeans-upgrader_pt_BR.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\nb\core\locale\org-netbeans-upgrader_ru.jar;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\nb\core\locale\org-netbeans-upgrader_zh_CN.jar
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.netbinox]: Install area set to file:/C:/Program Files/NetBeans 7.4/
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.modules]: the modules [org.netbeans.modules.form.nb] use org.jdesktop.layout which is deprecated: Use javax.swing.GroupLayout instead. (In form editor: select Form ... in Inspector; change Layout Generation Style to Standard Java 6 code.)
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.modules]: the modules [org.netbeans.modules.java.editor.lib, org.netbeans.modules.xml.text] use org.netbeans.modules.editor.deprecated.pre65formatting which is deprecated.
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.modules]: the modules [org.netbeans.modules.ide.kit, org.netbeans.modules.xml.text] use org.netbeans.modules.editor.structure which is deprecated.
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.modules]: the modules [org.netbeans.modules.apisupport.ant, org.netbeans.modules.java.hints, org.netbeans.modules.maven.hints] use org.netbeans.modules.java.hints.legacy.spi which is deprecated: Use Java Hints SPI (org.netbeans.spi.java.hints) instead.
WARNING [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: Not all children in Services/DiffProviders/ marked with the position attribute: [org-netbeans-modules-diff-cmdline-CmdlineDiffProvider.settings], but some are: [org-netbeans-modules-diff-builtin-provider-BuiltInDiffProvider.settings]
INFO [org.netbeans.core.startup.NbEvents]: Turning on modules:
    org.openide.util.lookup [8.22.1 201310111528]
    org.openide.util [8.33.1 201310111528]
.......
....... 
org.apache.xmlrpc [3.0.0 3.0.0]
    org.apache.commons.lang [2.4.0 2.4.0]
    com.jcraft.jzlib [1.0.7 1.0.7]
INFO [org.netbeans.core.netigso.Netigso]: bundle org.eclipse.osgi@3.8.0.v20120529-1548 started
INFO [org.netbeans.core.network.proxy.NetworkProxyReloader]: System network proxy resolver: Windows
INFO [org.netbeans.core.network.proxy.windows.WindowsNetworkProxy]: Windows system proxy resolver: auto detect
INFO [org.netbeans.core.network.proxy.NetworkProxyReloader]: System network proxy reloading succeeded.
INFO [org.netbeans.core.network.proxy.NetworkProxyReloader]: System network proxy - mode: direct
INFO [org.netbeans.core.network.proxy.NetworkProxyReloader]: System network proxy: falled to default (corect if direct mode went before)
INFO [org.openide.awt.Toolbar]: Too long AWTTask: 641 ms for org.openide.awt.MenuBar$MenuBarFolder@113998e(FolderList{MultiFileObject@1cca29c[Menu]})
WARNING [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: Not all children in FormDesignerPalette/SwingControls/ marked with the position attribute: [JXDatePicker.palette_item], but some are: [JLabel.palette_item, JButton.palette_item, JToggleButton.palette_item, JCheckBox.palette_item, JRadioButton.palette_item, ButtonGroup.palette_item, JComboBox.palette_item, JList.palette_item, JTextField.palette_item, JTextArea.palette_item, JScrollBar.palette_item, JSlider.palette_item, JProgressBar.palette_item, JFormattedTextField.palette_item, JPasswordField.palette_item, JSpinner.palette_item, JSeparator.palette_item, JTextPane.palette_item, JEditorPane.palette_item, JTree.palette_item, JTable.palette_item]
WARNING [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: Not all children in FormDesignerPalette/SwingMenus/ marked with the position attribute: [Customer.palette_item], but some are: [JMenuBar.palette_item, JMenu.palette_item, JMenuItem.palette_item, JCheckBoxMenuItem.palette_item, JRadioButtonMenuItem.palette_item, JPopupMenu.palette_item, JSeparator.palette_item]
WARNING [org.netbeans.TopSecurityManager]: use of system property netbeans.user has been obsoleted in favor of InstalledFileLocator/Places at org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seproject.J2SEProject$ProjectOpenedHookImpl$1$1.run(J2SEProject.java:607)
INFO [org.netbeans.core.windows.view.ui.TabbedHandler]: TopComponent has no icon: MVCTC[name=MPi.java, peer=[model=current=org.netbeans.core.spi.multiview.MultiViewFactory$MapMVD@268c1f]]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.updateprovider.DownloadListener]: Reading URL http://plugins.netbeans.org/nbpluginportal/updates/7.4/catalog.xml.gz failed (java.net.UnknownHostException: plugins.netbeans.org)
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.updateprovider.DownloadListener]: Reading URL http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/7.4/uc/final/distribution/catalog.xml.gz?unique=NBJDK_EXTIDE_JAVA_JDK02609260c-398b-4a40-935f-68c3c3944249_a8f341f1-08e2-4029-ac42-4bb81a51d240 failed (java.net.UnknownHostException: updates.netbeans.org)
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.updateprovider.DownloadListener]: Reading URL http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/7.4/uc/final/certified/catalog.xml.gz?unique=NBJDK_EXTIDE_JAVA_JDK02609260c-398b-4a40-935f-68c3c3944249_a8f341f1-08e2-4029-ac42-4bb81a51d240 failed (java.net.UnknownHostException: updates.netbeans.org)
WARNING [org.netbeans.TopSecurityManager]: use of system property netbeans.home has been obsoleted in favor of InstalledFileLocator/Places at org.netbeans.Clusters.relativeDirsWithHome(Clusters.java:137)
Diagnostic information
Input arguments:
    -Dnetbeans.importclass=org.netbeans.upgrade.AutoUpgrade
    -Dnetbeans.accept_license_class=org.netbeans.license.AcceptLicense
    -client
    -Xss2m
    -Xms32m
    -XX:PermSize=32m
    -Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true
    -Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true
    -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true
    -Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true
    -Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true
    -Xmx202m
    -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
    -Djdk.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51
    -Dnetbeans.home=C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\platform
    -Dnetbeans.user=C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Application Data\NetBeans\7.4
    -Dnetbeans.default_userdir_root=C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Application Data\NetBeans
    -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
    -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Application Data\NetBeans\7.4\var\log\heapdump.hprof
    -Dsun.awt.keepWorkingSetOnMinimize=true
    -Dnetbeans.dirs=C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\nb;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\ergonomics;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\ide;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\extide;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\java;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\apisupport;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\webcommon;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\websvccommon;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\enterprise;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\mobility;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\profiler;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\python;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\php;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\identity;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\harness;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\cnd;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\dlight;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\groovy;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\extra;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\javacard;C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\javafx
    exit
Compiler: HotSpot Client Compiler
Heap memory usage: initial 32.0MB maximum 195.3MB
Non heap memory usage: initial 54.2MB maximum 310.0MB
Garbage collector: Copy (Collections=58 Total time spent=0s)
Garbage collector: MarkSweepCompact (Collections=2 Total time spent=0s)
Classes: loaded=9161 total loaded=9173 unloaded 12
INFO [org.netbeans.core.ui.warmup.DiagnosticTask]: Total memory 1,063,297,024
INFO [org.openide.awt.Toolbar]: Too long AWTTask: 829 ms for org.openide.awt.MenuBar$LazyMenu$MenuFolder@1e347fa(FolderList{MultiFileObject@6e3645[Menu/View]})
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Resolving dependencies took: 172 ms
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Complete indexing of 20 binary roots took: 8,156 ms
INFO [org.openide.awt.Toolbar]: Too long AWTTask: 1,625 ms for org.openide.awt.MenuBar$LazyMenu$MenuFolder@1e24657(FolderList{MultiFileObject@a5bbf5[Menu/Refactoring]})
INFO [org.openide.awt.Toolbar]: Too long AWTTask: 703 ms for org.openide.awt.MenuBar$LazyMenu$MenuFolder@77fbbe(FolderList{MultiFileObject@156aef8[Menu/BuildProject]})
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: D:\Files\NetBeans Project\CfR\CfR_mis\src took: 3,235 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 125 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: D:\Files\NetBeans Project\CfR\CfR_Main\src took: 906 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 32 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: D:\Files\NetBeans Project\CfR\CfR_Main\test took: 547 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 15 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: D:\Files\NetBeans Project\CfR\CfR_mis\test took: 312 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Complete indexing of 4 source roots took: 5,000 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 172 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Resolving dependencies took: 47 ms
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Complete indexing of 0 binary roots took: 0 ms
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\ide\jsstubs\reststubs.zip took: 828 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\ide\jsstubs\corestubs.zip took: 594 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.options.keymap.LayersBridge]: Invalid shortcut: org.openide.loaders.BrokenDataShadow@13a4819[MultiFileObject@ecbef8[Keymaps/NetBeans/D-BACK_QUOTE.shadow]]
WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.options.keymap.LayersBridge]: Invalid shortcut: org.openide.loaders.BrokenDataShadow@13a4819[MultiFileObject@ecbef8[Keymaps/NetBeans/D-BACK_QUOTE.shadow]]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Indexing of: C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\ide\jsstubs\domstubs.zip took: 797 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Complete indexing of 3 source roots took: 2,219 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Resolving dependencies took: 62 ms
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Complete indexing of 0 binary roots took: 0 ms
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Complete indexing of 0 source roots took: 0 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Resolving dependencies took: 16 ms
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Complete indexing of 0 binary roots took: 0 ms
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.indexing.RepositoryUpdater]: Complete indexing of 0 source roots took: 0 ms (New or modified files: 0, Deleted files: 0) [Adding listeners took: 0 ms]
```

Comment: check the netbeans log files, [edit] your question to post relevant log files and errors. Voting to close for lack of context.

Comment: Dear Matt Clark, I have posted few lines of log file and need more to understand log file as I am new to java. The file is a big one, otherwise I could have posted the entire file. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Hi Dghosh, thanks for that, however this does not seem to help. Could you do the following: close netbeans, clear the existing log file, relaunch netbeans and reproduce the crash. Then reupload that log file - it may give some better information; look for stack traces and errors.

Comment: Dear Matt Clark, I have posted most of the log file this time. I have deleted few lines of Turning on modules: as post is only limited to 30000 chars. Hope that will solve your purpose. Thanks for your help.